# Fastest way to compare binary data?

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I have data in the form of `0010011` or `[False, False, True, False, False, True, True]`. There are roughly 10 million examples of this format, which have not seven but one thousand values each.

In my use case, I'm getting a new entry in the same form. Then, I want to get the indexes of the 100 most equal entries. Here, most equal is defined as having the most intersecting `1`s or `True`s respectivly. E.g., the two entries `00011` and `00010` have one intersecting `1`.

Currently, I'm doing the comparison like this:

```
similarties = []
for idx, binary_1 in enumerate(complete_list):
    similarties += [(idx, np.binary_repr(binary_1 & binary_2).count('1'))]
similarties.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

For 10000 random test entries, this takes 0.2 seconds. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: So `111111` is more equal to `001100` than `000100` is?

Comment: Yes, the intersecting `1`s are what counts

Comment: Btw. shouldn't that be `(binary_1 & binary_2)` in your snippet?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right.

Comment: Are your entries Python long ints? Perhaps one could gain some speed by using a more numpy friendly format.

Comment: I'm flexible in what data type to store the values in

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** found a threefold speedup.

Here is an approach that uses numpy on packed bits to save memory. To convert between this format and individual `0`s and `1`s of type `uint8` numpy provides functions `packbits` and `unpackbits`.

The code below precomputes the sums for all `2^16` patterns that can be formed by chunks of 16 bits.

(The old version did the lookup for pairs of bytes in the data and the template)

We use view casting to `uint64` to perfom the bitwise intersection on chunks of `64` bits and then cast back to `uint16` for lookup.

To find the `n` closest we use `argpartition` (O(N)) instead of `argsort` (O(N log N)).

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 1_000_000, 1_000

data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (n, (m + 63) // 64 * 8), dtype=np.uint8)
test = np.random.randint(0, 256, ((m + 63) // 64 * 8,), dtype=np.uint8)

def create_lookup_1d():
    x, p = np.ogrid[:1<<16, :16]
    p = 1 << p
    return np.count_nonzero(x & p, axis=1)

lookup_1d = create_lookup_1d()

def find_closest(data, test, n):
    similarities = lookup_1d[(data.view(np.uint64) & test.view(np.uint64))
                             .view(np.uint16)].sum(axis=1)
    top_n = np.argpartition(similarities, len(data)-n)[-n:]
    return top_n, similarities[top_n]

# below is obsolete older version

def create_lookup_2d():
    x, y, p = np.ogrid[:256, :256, :8]
    p = 1 << p
    return np.count_nonzero(x & y & p, axis=2)

lookup_2d = create_lookup_2d()

def find_closest_old(data, test, n):
    similarities = lookup_2d[data, test].sum(axis=1)
    top_n = np.argpartition(similarities, len(data)-n)[-n:]
    return top_n, similarities[top_n]
```

Demo (one million entries, one thousand bits each, find hundred best):

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.perf_counter(); find_closest(data, test, 100); t = time.perf_counter() - t
(array([913659, 727762, 819589, 810536, 671392, 573459, 197431, 642848,
         8792, 710169, 656667, 692412,  23355, 695527, 276548, 756096,
       286481, 931702, 301590, 309232, 223684, 838507, 888607, 205403,
       988198, 600239, 256834, 876452, 793813,  46501, 559521, 697295,
       948215, 247923, 503962, 808630, 515953,  22821, 614888, 487735,
       443673, 174083, 906902, 613131, 546603, 147657, 332898, 381553,
       808760, 383885, 107547,  85942,  20966, 880034, 522925,  18833,
       547674, 901503, 702596, 773050, 734658, 383581, 973043, 387713,
       645705,  27045, 230226,  77403, 906601, 507193, 828268, 175863,
       708155, 130634, 486701, 534719, 643487, 940071, 694781, 470385,
       954446, 134532, 748100, 110987, 417001, 871320, 993915, 489725,
         6509,  38345, 705618, 637435, 311252, 347282, 536091, 663643,
       830238, 376695, 896090, 823631]), array([305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305,
       305, 306, 305, 306, 306, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 306, 305, 306,
       305, 306, 314, 308, 307, 309, 306, 308, 307, 308, 307, 312, 308,
       306, 316, 306, 306, 307, 307, 308, 309, 308, 307, 309, 309, 311,
       309, 310, 310, 307, 307, 306, 307, 306, 307, 309, 308, 309, 308,
       306, 307, 309, 306, 306, 306, 311, 306, 308, 307, 306, 306, 307,
       308, 306, 307, 310, 307, 306, 307, 309, 306, 306, 310, 313, 306,
       306, 307, 310, 306, 307, 307, 309, 311, 307]))
>>> t
0.4612512579988106
```

Comment: Impressive. How would you value using np.packbits? This would shrink the size of the matrix significally

Comment: I'd recommend using it. The code I posted assumes `packbits` has already been applied. Just be sure to zero pad every line to a multiple of 64 bits. (`packbits` only pads to multiples of 8)

Comment: Different question: When looking at your results, the values of intersections are all slightly above 300, but why aren't they in order?

Comment: Because `argpartition` doesn't sort, it just splits into two parts such that no item in the first part is larger than any item in the second. Even if you need the result sorted it's probably cheaper first to partition and then to sort only the `100` most similar

Answer (score 0):

Using broadcasting might help here. For example,

```
import numpy as np

complete_list = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10000, 10)).astype(bool)
binary_2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10).astype(bool)

similarities = np.sum(complete_list & binary_2, axis=1)
idx = np.argsort(similarities)

print("Seed", binary_2)
print("Result", complete_list[idx[-1]])
print("Similarity", similarities[idx[-1]])
```

I couldn't get your example to run (maybe different python/library versions?) so haven't run any benchmarks comparing the two approaches. Of course, our machines will be different but the above takes about half a millisecond on mine.

Note that I've used `&` rather than `|` given your description of the intended logic.